# app enigine 1.9.18, JDO 3.1.3 java.lang.ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm having this exception when I call

```
jobInDatabase = pm.getObjectById(DAOJob.class, job.getKey());
```

Causes the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
at com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob.jdoReplaceField(DAOJob.java)
at com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob.jdoReplaceFields(DAOJob.java)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1935)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1962)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.fetchObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:567)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadFieldsFromDatastore(JDOStateManager.java:1638)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.validate(JDOStateManager.java:3511)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3379)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1722)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1740)
at com.eurekaapp.server.dao.GoogleCloud.getJob(GoogleCloud.java:712)
at com.eurekaapp.server.service.DAOServiceImpl.getJob(DAOServiceImpl.java:661)
at com.eurekaapp.server.api.client.AddJobEvent.doPost(AddJobEvent.java:55)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:527)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm not sure which field is throwing this exception?
I've 3 doubles in the obj -
weight  0
deliveryLongitude  0
deliveryLatitude  0

and the rest of the numbers are longs.  This is only happening with this one object at the moment.

These values are set by default if no value is passed in. Going forward, maybe if I set these default values to represent actual doubles, it would rectify this problem.

Here are some of the logs on the server leading up to the exception:

```
    I 12:16:05.092 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,091 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:doPost:45 - user.isParsingSuccessfull()
I 12:16:05.093 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,092 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:isReceivedVersionCorrect:1830 - isReceivedVersionCorrect(): starting
I 12:16:05.094 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,093 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:isReceivedVersionCorrect:1833 - isReceivedVersionCorrect(): try
I 12:16:05.095 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,094 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:isReceivedVersionCorrect:1837 - isReceivedVersionCorrect(): version correct, version[17]
I 12:16:05.096 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,095 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:isReceivedVersionCorrect:1846 - isReceivedVersionCorrect(): successfull true
I 12:16:05.097 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,096 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:doPost:47 - daoService.isReceivedVersionCorrect(passedJSONArray.getJSONObject(0))
I 12:16:05.098 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,097 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:doPost:49 - passedJSONArray[1]
I 12:16:05.099 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,098 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:isReceivedJobEventValid:1962 - isReceivedJobEventValid(): starting
I 12:16:05.100 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,099 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:isReceivedJobEventValid:1965 - isReceivedJobEventValid(): try
I 12:16:05.101 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,100 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:isReceivedJobEventValid:1989 - DAOJobEvent() jobEvent.setParsingSuccessfull(true); DAOJobEvent [key=null, localID=95, jobID=5351674944159744, eventType=11, eventTime=Sun Mar 22 19:07:08 UTC 2015, latitude=53.325, longitude=-6.32569, notes=This job has been finished automatically by the phone, storedEventTime=Mon Mar 23 12:16:05 UTC 2015, companyID=6037653766012928, userID=6012377212387328, nanoTime=3020586876124620, sequence=null]
I 12:16:05.102 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,101 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:isReceivedJobEventValid:1996 - DAOJobEvent() returning
I 12:16:05.103 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,102 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 class:getJob:706 - getJob(): starting
I 12:16:05.104 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,103 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Cache:debug:58 - Level 1 Cache of type "soft" initialised
I 12:16:05.105 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,104 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Persistence:debug:58 - Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1456e6b" opened for datastore "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager@ba090c" with txn="org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl@1544f26"
I 12:16:05.107 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,106 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Cache:debug:58 - Object with id "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob:5351674944159744" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 0]
I 12:16:05.108 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,107 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Cache:debug:58 - Object with id "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob:5351674944159744" not found in Level 2 cache
I 12:16:05.109 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,108 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Cache:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob@4adf6a" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob:5351674944159744") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN]")
I 12:16:05.181 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,109 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Lifecycle:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob@4adf6a" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob:5351674944159744") has a lifecycle change : "HOLLOW"->"P_NONTRANS"
I 12:16:05.182 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,181 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Connection:debug:58 - Created ManagedConnection using DatastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl@191c505
I 12:16:05.183 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,182 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Connection:debug:58 - Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@11de9d0 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1456e6b in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@f2b4dc]
I 12:16:05.185 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,184 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Connection:debug:58 - Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@11de9d0 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1456e6b in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@f2b4dc]
I 12:16:05.186 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,185 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Native:debug:58 - Getting entity of kind DAOJob with key DAOJob(5351674944159744)
I 12:16:05.196 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,195 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Retrieve:debug:58 - Fetching object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob@4adf6a" (id=5351674944159744) fields [acceptStatus,check1,check2,check3,check4,check5,collectionAddress,companyID,containerCode,customerName,customerref,deliveryLatitude,deliveryLongitude,deliveryaddress,deliverytime,enumStatus,groupID,instructions,jobType,jobTypeID,key,lastmodified,localID,notes,parsingSuccessfull,quantity1,quantity2,quantity3,quantity4,ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5,required_ItemCount,required_Note,required_POD,required_Signature,required_SignatureName,trailerCode,uniqueField,userID,vehicleCode,weight]
I 12:16:05.197 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,196 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Retrieve:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob@4adf6a" (id="5351674944159744") being retrieved from AppEngine
I 12:16:05.199 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,197 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Persistence:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob@4adf6a" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob:5351674944159744") is having the value in field "deliverytime" replaced by a SCO wrapper
I 12:16:05.200 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,199 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Persistence:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob@4adf6a" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob:5351674944159744") is having the value in field "lastmodified" replaced by a SCO wrapper
I 12:16:05.201 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,200 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Connection:debug:58 - Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@11de9d0 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1456e6b in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@f2b4dc] but owner object closing so closing connection
I 12:16:05.202 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,201 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Connection:debug:58 - Connection removed from the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@11de9d0 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1456e6b in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@f2b4dc]
I 12:16:05.203 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,202 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Persistence:debug:58 - Disconnecting com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob@4adf6a from StateManager[pc=com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob@4adf6a, lifecycle=P_NONTRANS]
I 12:16:05.204 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,203 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Cache:debug:58 - Object with id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob:5351674944159744" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 1]
I 12:16:05.205 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,204 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Cache:debug:58 - Level 1 Cache cleared
I 12:16:05.206 [s~server-test-/17.383086902326406416].<stdout>: 12:16:05,205 DEBUG Request 6CDEEF07 Persistence:debug:58 - Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1456e6b" closed
```

-Any suggestions?

Comment: I've manually went in and updated the double values in the datastore to 0.0 and saved it.

Comment: Did you set the type to "float" when you updated this values? Also, remember to clear the cache.

Comment: Hi Andrei, nope, the type is set to double. I'm parsing all doubles from a JSON and setting them using setters that set each double value on the object before making persistent. I never clear the cache though, what would be good practice in relation to this? When would be a good time to clear, like every hour or so?

Comment: There are only `float` and `int` types in the Datastore viewer. Internally, all values are stored as Double or Long. You don't need to clear the cache unless you make manual changes through the Datastore viewer, or you make changes in your data model and the like.

Comment: Ahh, so I really shouldn't be editing my data using the datastore viewer. Fair enough. That's what might have caused this. Let's say though this error happens again, I was thinking of providing a method that allows an admin to call a 'clean cache' method. Do you know if this error happens a lot? Do you think this is necessary that I provide this method? I know it's not necessary, but I can't have this error happening. My project is only after going live and I'm slowly ramping up the users. I'm going to try replicate this issue by editing a double value in the datastore viewer

Comment: OK, I'm confused now. I updated a double value with just the number '1' and saved it. But that job is still returning 0 as that field: 11:14:18,110 DEBUG Request 26065572 Cache:debug:58 - Object "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob@297acd" (id="com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJob:6142007311335424") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN]")              ->  This is the field I updated -> weight=0.0. This value should be set to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user Andrei Volgin comment above was correct.

The datastore viewer fields are only float and int types. I edited a double value and it was stored as a Long.

I tried to replicate the issue by updating a field and initially it did not replicate, because it was getting the original object from the JDO cache.

Once a new instance started up on GAE
"This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."

And JDO went to retireve my newly updated object, I got a java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double.

Bottom line, don't update double values using the datastore viewer